# Parsing script with Powershell through Automic scheduler

Tags: powershell, text-parsing, automic

Im doing a project on Trizetto Elements and the file naming is said to be variable so I made a parsing script to make sure Im grabbing the right file when we begin the batch loading.  Works great on my desktop but as soon as I plug it into Automic scheduler it starts complaining about not being able to load values into empty arrays.

I tried loading as a batch script and running through the automic Powershell interpreter and got similar results

```
################Load file content into variables##########
$array = GCI -Path "F:\Originpath"
$num = $array.Count - 1   
for ($i=0; $i -le $num; $i++ ){$text[$i]

    $text[$i]= get-content $array[$i]|select -First 10

    "Parsing first ten rows of file" + " " + ($array[$i])

     write-host $text[$i]}
####################Evaluate file contents for match####################
      for ($b=0; $b -le $num; $b++ ){
      if($text[$b]| Select-String -Pattern '.*,H9047,.*,51,'){
           Move-Item -path $array[$b] -destination "F\:destination path\"
                }}
```

I expect that it will move the correct file to the destination, instead I get

```
c:\>powershell -File F:\Automic\Agents\Windows\Resources\0001\0002378703\0002378703_0001.ps1 
Cannot index into a null array.
At F:\Automic\Agents\Windows\Resources\0001\0002378703\0002378703_0001.ps1:5 char:5
+     $text[$i]= get-content ($array[$i])|select -First 10
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised the text array: $text[$i]

Instead try something like:

```
$text = @()
$num = $array.Count - 1   
for ($i=0; $i -le $num; $i++ ){
    $text+= get-content $array[$i]|select -First 10
```

etc